# Restsharp Xamarin iOS does not honor timeout for RestSharp

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, restsharp

I am using RestSharp in Xamarin 4 to make a network call with the specified timeout

```
var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.GET) { Timeout = 5000 };
var response = await _client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync(request);
return response;
```

This works as expected in android. It times out in 5 seconds in case of no response.
However, on iOS, the call fails to time out.It takes approx. 60-75 seconds for it to time out.

Is there something I am missing or some bug with Xamarin or restsharp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there seems to be a bug for Async operations with Rest clients For Xamarin iOS.

Same code works perfectly on Android .
We tested following scenario -: Start the request with `_client.ExecuteGetTaskAsync`. When the request is in progress , disconnect the network. On iOS the await call doesn't return immediately.In Android it returns immediately.

I tried setting readWriteTimeOut on iOS.And that setting worked on iOS.But need to check its side effects.We need to test whether readwriteTimeout affects operation on a slow speed network.